# reconfigure in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет!
Помогите решить одну задачу, что-то зашел в тупик с ней, заранее спасибо!

В общем создаю процедуру и в ее теле будет запускаться xp_cmdshell для создания файла, далее этот файл прикрепляется к письму и отправляется по почте.

Для этого идет:

```
...
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
...
```

Но, выводит ошибки:

> configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. run
>   the reconfigure statement to install config statement cannot be used
>   inside a user transaction configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed
>   from 1 to 1. run the reconfigure statement to install config statement
>   cannot be used inside a user transaction

Если использовать так, то без ошибок, файл создается, но письмо не улетает:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'sp_configure ''show advanced options'', 1; reconfigure; '
EXEC ('RECONFIGURE')
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', 1; reconfigure;'
EXEC ('RECONFIGURE')
```